# simple algorithm to increment two values

Tags: c#, .net

```
if (stack == "1" && tray == 6)
{
    stack = "2";
    tray = 1;
}
else if (stack == "2" && tray == 12)
{
    stack = "1";
    tray = 2;
}

tray++;
```

i just need to increment stack, tray this way:

```
    1, 1
    1, 2
    1, 3
    ...
    1, 6
    ...
  2, 1
    2, 2
    2, 3
    2, 4
    ...
    ...
2,12
    1,2
    ..
    ..
```

the above code works fine for me; however, i would like to know if there is a better, more succinct way of rewriting this?

Comment: Should `stack` really be a string type?

Comment: Code examples are fine, but try to describe in plain English what you want to do.

Comment: Since `stack` is a string there's no good way to do math on it, so I'd say this is about the best you can do.

Comment: Is the incremental of `tray` always by 6?

Comment: @Gabe: Because parsing a string and getting a number is impossible.

Comment: @Stefan: The OP wanted a *more* succint way to write it!

Comment: @Gabe: Look at the updated example.

Answer (score 5):

Off the top of my head, it seems that what you're trying to do is combine a base 6 and a base 10 number.  You should be able to do that by thinking of this as a fixed point number with a multiplier of 6.

```
public class StackTray {
    int _stackTray;
    public StackTray() : this(0, 0) { }
    public StackTray(int stack, int tray)
    {
        if (stack < 0) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("stack");
        if (tray < 0 || tray >= 6) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("tray");
        _stackTray = stack * 6 + tray;
    }
    public int Stack { get { return _stackTray / 6; } }
    public int Tray { get { return _stackTray % 6; } }
    public void Increment() { _stackTray++; }
    public void Decrement() { if( _stackTray == 0) return; _stackTray--; }
}
```

Note that the values you get will be 0-based, not 1 based as in your example.

In use:

```
StackTray st = new StackTray();
for (int i=0; i < 10; i++) {
    st.Increment();
    Console.WriteLine("Stack: {0} Tray: {1}", st.Stack + 1, st.Tray + 1); // tada - one based
}
for (int i=0; i < 5; i++) {
    st.Decrement();
    Console.WriteLine("Stack: {0} Tray: {1}", st.Stack, st.Tray); // tada - zero based
}
```

You can inbuild the 1 based in the Stack and Tray properties, but I think this violates the principle of least astonishment.  C# is a 0-based language, not a 1-based language.

Comment: @plin this tremendously complicates my example

Comment: @JOE SKEET: how so? Many of us would consider this much simpler than your example.

Comment: @sixl, who else besides u would consider this simpler than what i wrote

Comment: Complicated?  I don't see how encapsulation is complication.  I considered also encapsulating the magic number or at least making it a class constant, but thought it detracted from readability of the example.  I also considered making arbitrary add/subtract but with argument checking, this also complicates the example.  You might also want to note that except for error checking in the constructor, every operation is a 1-liner.

Comment: @plin so how would i make this 1 based

Comment: @plin im sorry how would i even use this?

Comment: @plin so u are not answering the question, u are giving me 0 but i need 1

Comment: Excuse me for being terse, but I'm not your dancing monkey.  There's ample example code on how to use the class and how to make it 1 based.

Answer (score 0):

Create an object with proper `hashCode` and `equals`, like this

```
class State{
String stack
int tray
}
```

And build a transition map

```
Map<State,State> transitionMap = new Map...
transitionMap.put( new State( "2", 12 ), new State( "1", 2 ) )...
```

Then, you can transition states by looking up the transition map. Then just increment tray. I'm assuming your real code is more complex than this, but this is probably the most flexible solution.

use C# syntax and metaphors where appropriate.

Comment: Probably not. What part of this don't you understand?

Comment: Also, this probably isn't what you're looking for, given the added example you gave.